# Ошибка в программе Assembler

Tags: ассемблер

Доброй ночи, всем активным участникам этого замечательного форума. помогите, пожалуйста, помочь разобраться в ошибке.

Задание:
Создать программу на языке Ассемблер, что позволяет организовать вычисления (сложение и вычитание) по формуле K=(a+5)-(c+d)+(e-f-7+a).

Вот программа:

```
format MZ
start:    mov ax,cs
  mov ds,ax
    mov al,[a]
    add al,5
    mov dl,al
    mov al,[c]
    add al,[d]
    sub dl,al
    mov al,[e]
    sub al,[f]
    sub al,7
    add al,[a]
    add al,dl
    mov ah,4Ch
    int 21h
;--------------
a db 5
c dw 2
d dw 4
e dw 67
f dw 12
```

ОШИБКА В СТРОЧКЕ:

> mov al,[ac]

Заранее огромное спасибо всем за помощь!

Comment: @Alison Dilaurentis, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ОШИБКА В СТРОЧКЕ: mov al,[ac]

У вас нет переменной ac.